# How to not repeat code in select function of Jquery UI autocomplete feature

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, repeat

I have two jquery ui autocomplete boxes on a large form (probably with 40 or more fields).
The user can search two ways using two different autocomplete boxes (either by name or an account number).
I am populating the other fields on the form when the user selects his search result.
However, I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it.

Currently, this is what I have.

```
    $( "#search-by-custname" ).autocomplete({
    source: "cust_search_by_name.php",
    minLength: 4,
    select: function(event, ui){
        $('#Custid').val(ui.item.Custid);
        $('#Alpha1').val(ui.item.Alpha1);
        $('#CustName').val(ui.item.CustName);
    }
    });
    $( "#search-by-custalpha1" ).autocomplete({
    source: "cust_search_by_alpha1.php",
    minLength: 4,
    select: function(event, ui){
        $('#Custid').val(ui.item.Custid);
        $('#Alpha1').val(ui.item.Alpha1);
        $('#CustName').val(ui.item.CustName);
    }
    });
```

The php files are grabbing data from a remote data source, and everything works ok.

The problem is, if I reference all of those fields twice inside of each autocomplete box, that will be a lot of lines of code... I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it.

I played around with writing my own function, but, I'm a noob to javascript and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work but I can't see why it wouldn't.

```
    var selectFunc = function(event, ui){
        $('#Custid').val(ui.item.Custid);
        $('#Alpha1').val(ui.item.Alpha1);
        $('#CustName').val(ui.item.CustName);
    };

    $( "#search-by-custname" ).autocomplete({
    source: "cust_search_by_name.php",
    minLength: 4,
    select: selectFunc
    });
    $( "#search-by-custalpha1" ).autocomplete({
    source: "cust_search_by_alpha1.php",
    minLength: 4,
    select: selectFunc
    });
```